# mercurial - have I lost a commit after checking out parent and commiting there?

Tags: mercurial

I committed some changes in hg, then checked out the parent of that commit and made other changes followed by another commit (from that parent).

What happened to the 1st commit? How can I find and recover it? I don't see it in the log.

Answer (score 2):

> What happened to the 1st commit?

It should still be there.  Making the extra commit should have just created another head within the branch.

> How can I find and recover it?

It should also be obvious (for finding), in Mercurial, which makes me wonder:

> I don't see it in the log.

How exactly are you looking at the commit log?  If you just run `hg log` or `hg log -b <branch>`, you should see all commits, or all commits in the given branch, in reverse numerical order.  If you use `hg log --follow`, commits not reachable from the current commit *will* seem to disappear, because, as the documentation says:

> > `--follow` without a filename will only show ancestors or descendants of the starting revision.

In any case, you can do revision surgery if you really want to, but the simplest thing is just to merge the heads.  Use `hg heads .` to view the heads in the current branch; check out one, and merge another, to combine the two commits with a new merge commit, making both previous heads become ordinary non-head commits, with the new merge being a single head in that branch.